How can I access the IIS `REMOTE_USER` environment variable inside of an httpPlatformHandler process?
Background
I am trying to set up a Django application to use Windows Authentication via IIS. The Django documentation says that you can authenticate with the REMOTE_USER environment variable set by IIS.
We deploy our Django applications via httpPlatformHandler, which requires that any environment variables be declared outright in order to be passed. I'm assuming this is also the case with the REMOTE_USER because when I print os.environ.get("REMOTE_USER"), it's None.
Question
Does anyone know of a way to dynamically pass the REMOTE_USER environment variable through to the httpPlatform process?
Is that even the right way to approach it? I'm assuming the environment variable would change for each user that attempted to access the process, am I barking up the wrong tree entirely?
Things I've Tried
I've tried setting an environment variable to be
<environmentVariable name="REMOTE_USER" value="%REMOTE_USER%" />

But that just sets it to be literally %REMOTE_USER%, which is not what we want. I've also tried %HTTP_REMOTE_USER% which doesn't work either.
I've tried setting forwardWindowsAuthToken to true, but that just adds an unrelated header that Django isn't looking for.
Any help, suggestions, or anything would be greatly appreciated!

I think Python web apps should actually decrypt the Windows user token (as the previous thread indicated). If Django doesn't support that yet, you might extend it.
